# PHP mysqli_query won't execute

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write my first basic PHP RESTful API - I managed to get it working on my local machine using MAMP. But when I uploaded to hosting server, it doesn't want to work.

Code below - I've added some ECHO's in there to make sure things are working along the way. It seems like we're all good up until the `$result=mysqli_query`.

```
<?php

//header('Content-type:application/json');

    // Connect to db
    $con = mysqli_connect("HOSTNAME","USER","PASSWORD","DATABASE");

    echo "Database: ";
    // Check connection
    if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully";
    echo "<br><br>";

    // Get value from url
    $bid = $_GET['bid'];
    echo "BID: ";
    echo $bid;
    echo "<br><br>";

    // Define Query
    $sql = "SELECT id, bandname, members, bio, songlist FROM bands WHERE id='$bid'";
    echo "SQL Query: ";
    echo $sql;
    echo "<br><br>";

    // Run Query
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    echo "Result: ";
    print_r($result);
    echo "<br><br>";

    // Put Query result into array
    $result_array = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo "Result Array: ";
    print_r($result_array);
    echo "<br><br>";

    // Encode array as JSON and output
    echo "JSON: ";
    echo json_encode($result_array);

?>
```

The url I'm entering is http://bandsly.com/api.php?bid=1 and this is the output I'm getting in the browser...

```
Database: Connected successfully

BID: 1

SQL Query: SELECT id, bandname, members, bio, songlist FROM bands WHERE id='1'

Result: 

Result Array: 

JSON: null
```

When I manually run the query `SELECT id, bandname, members, bio, songlist FROM bands WHERE id='1'` in the database (PHPmyadmin), it works fine and I get 1 row returned with the correct values.

The manual db query result:
[image]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3ZPJ.png)

Any help would be most appreciated!!

*****EDIT*****

OK, i think i found the issue... My "successfully Connected" wasn't written correctly, and always came back looking good. It looks like after fixing that, i have db connection issues.

I'm going to go look up the db connection settings and try and fix that.

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: You can use `mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`

Comment: $con = mysqli_connect("HOSTNAME","USER","PASSWORD","DATABASE"); here is everything ok?

Comment: thanks @aldrin27 - i'll try that to keep it lean.

Comment: thanks @M0rtiis - Yea, i just changed this for purposes of post. My browser comes back with "connected successfully" so i think we're ok there.

Comment: this query is working perfactly for me . there may be another reason .

Comment: Can you put this to check whether query is being executed by `mysqli_query` as `if (mysqli_query($con, $sql) === TRUE) {`

Comment: the link you provided shows a connection error

Comment: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/494275/c6c255cd6924d07196076b32489489de

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injections use prepared statements don't pass user input direct to your queries.

Comment: @ManojDhiman Thanks all - On further investigation... it's definitely a db connect issue. Loks like i have some hunting on godaddy (sigh) to identify the right credentials for my db settings.

Comment: yes there is a connection problem .

Comment: You are fetching data from `$_GET` and putting it directly to a query, this is unsafe. You should filter data to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your all code is correct, I have tested in my local just change your 
HOSTNAME like "localhost", USER like "root", PASSWORD like "your password", DATABASE like "YOUR DATABASE NAME".

```
$con = mysqli_connect("HOSTNAME","USER","PASSWORD","DATABASE");
```

please, visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be ok on my localsystem http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/494275/c6c255cd6924d07196076b32489489de. There should be a connection problem . so you can do some try to check connection like

check the details in

```
 // Connect to db
    $con = mysqli_connect("HOSTNAME","USER","PASSWORD","DATABASE");
```

and then you can try to ping database

```
/* check connection */
if ($con->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $con->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/* check if server is alive */
if ($con->ping()) {
    printf ("Our connection is ok!\n");
} else {
    printf ("Error: %s\n", $con->error);
}
```